# Pivot and Unpivot from the same table to create parallel records

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot, group

I have a table of contents as below  with so many records and a matching ID to all the different fields. what am trying it so unpivot and pivot at the same time.  lets dive in.

| NIN | SECTION | RESULT | INCONSISTANCE | COMMENT | CORRECTION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CM92027100U63F | Registration Number | W9023 | TYPO | False | WE0029 |
| CM92027100U63F | Employee Number | 108W2438 | INVALID NO | 299P306 |  |
| CM92027100U63F | Supplier Number | 192Q93 | INVALID LENGTH | 19Q93 |  |
| CM92027100U63F | Employee Name | MUKASA PETER | N/A | N/A | N/A |

I have unpivoted the table turning the section contents into columns and picking values from NIN and RESULT for each created columns.

| NIN | Employee Name | Registration Number | Employee Number | Supplier Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CM92027100U63F | MUKASA PETER | W9023 | 108W2438 | 192Q93 |

```sql
                    ;WITH CTE(
         NIN,
        [Registration Number],
        [Employee Number],
        [Supplier Number], 
        [Employee Name]
        )
         AS
         (
         SELECT TOP(100) [EmployeeNIN],

             MAX(CASE WHEN  [KeySection] ='Registration Number'                     THEN  [Result]   END),
                MAX(CASE WHEN  [KeySection] ='Employee Number'                      THEN  [Result]   END),
                MAX(CASE WHEN  [KeySection] ='Supplier Number'                      THEN  [Result]   END),
                MAX(CASE WHEN  [KeySection] ='Employee Name'                        THEN  [Result]   END)
 
             FROM [dbo].[Observations] GROUP BY NIN
        )

         SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

the challenge I am having now is to add contents from the other columns  **INCONSISTANCE,COMMENT,CORRECTION** to all the corresponding rows under the created columns to get this result.

|  | NIN | Employee Name | Registration Number | Employee Number | Supplier Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | CM920271063F | MUKASA PETER | W9023 | 108W2438 | 192Q93 |
| INCONSISTANCE | N/A | TYPO | INVALID NO | INVALID LENGTH | N/A |
| COMMENT | N/A | Not Matching | 299P306 | 19Q93 | N/A |
| CORRECTION | N/A | WE0029 |  |  | N/A |

Comment: Presumably you need to *unpivot* these columns and union with your pivoted results.

Comment: OK let me try that

Comment: am gonna need a lill guidance here, on a pivot when i have no colum with numbers

Answer (score 1):

```
select case col when 'RESULT' then null else col end type,
   case col when 'RESULT' then nin_val else null end nin,
   [Employee Name], [Employee Number], [Registration Number], [Supplier Number]
from (
  select nin nin_val, col, val, section
  from Observations
  unpivot (val for col in (result, inconsistance, comment, correction)) u ) u
pivot (max(val) for section in ([Employee Name], 
  [Employee Number], [Registration Number], [Supplier Number])) p
order by nin_val, 
  case col when 'RESULT' then 1 when 'INCONSISTANCE' then 2 
           when 'COMMENT' then 3 when 'CORRECTION' then 4 end
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/PWgUxCRu)

Unpivot columns result, inconsistance, comment, correction.

Pivot columns [Employee Number], [Registration Number], [Supplier Number].

Apply logic for first two columns in output using `case when...`.

Order result conditionally.

Comment: wow this is great, it actually is working. thanx

Comment: What if  the comment,correction & inconsistency where to run side by side with each unpivoted column  like .                                                                                   
        NIN |Employee Name |INCONSISTANCE|COMMENT|CORRECTION|Registration Number|INCONSISTANCE|COMMENT|CORRECTION|Employee Number     i have tried to edit that code but came up empty